# java program , it Doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, awt

We made the program for Library management, 
here S,Korea, 
so some words, you can't see them but they are not sources.

we have tried many times to fix it but yet has not worked

1. we run the this program and then show up the popup-frame which is separated by two sections, one is the list menu for books(Korean) and the other is book's image showed up(at first, gray window you can see it)

we designed it that pops up the open_file  after event button which is under the gray window, which is chosen some images
2.after pushing this button, wait wait wait... there is no event to (no open file)
  =>switch to image 
**The Issue is:** Even though we are clicking on the button but nothing happens. No action command is fired when we click on button

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class BookInfo extends Frame {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Frame
        final FileDialog fc = null;


        Frame f = new Frame();
        f.setBounds(200, 200, 500, 350);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {

               public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       System.exit(0);
                }
           });

        // 글꼴
        Font font = new Font("궁서", Font.BOLD, 15);
        Font font2 = new Font("궁서", Font.BOLD, 20);


        // title
        Label title = new Label("============   도   서   정   보   ============");
        title.setFont(font2);
        title.setBounds(1, 40, 800, 40);
        f.add(title);

        // 관리번호
        Label bookNum = new Label("관리번호 : ");
        bookNum.setFont(font);  // 글꼴 적용
        bookNum.setBounds(30, 100, 80, 50);
        f.add(bookNum);


        TextField bNum = new TextField("");
        bNum.setFont(font);
        bNum.setBounds(110, 110, 100, 30);
        f.add(bNum);

        // 도서명
        Label bookTitle = new Label("도  서  명 :  ");
        bookTitle.setFont(font);
        bookTitle.setBounds(30, 140, 80, 50);
        f.add(bookTitle);

        TextField bTitle = new TextField("");
        bTitle.setFont(font);
        bTitle.setBounds(110, 155, 100, 30);
        f.add(bTitle);


        // 저자명
        Label writer = new Label("저  자  명 :  ");
        writer.setBounds(30, 180, 80, 50);
        writer.setFont(font);
        f.add(writer);
        TextField wr = new TextField("");
        wr.setFont(font);
        wr.setBounds(110, 193, 100, 30);
        f.add(wr);



        // 출판사
        Label company = new Label("출  판  사 :  ");
        company.setBounds(30, 220, 80, 50);
        company.setFont(font);
        f.add(company);
        TextField com = new TextField("");
        com.setFont(font);
        com.setBounds(110, 235, 100, 30);
        f.add(com);

        // 가격
        Label price = new Label("가        격 :  ");
        price.setBounds(30, 260, 80, 50);
        price.setFont(font);
        f.add(price);
        TextField prc = new TextField("");
        prc.setFont(font);
        prc.setBounds(110, 275, 100, 30);
        f.add(prc);

        // 도서 이미지 
        Canvas c = new Canvas();
        c.setBounds(300, 100, 130, 180);
        c.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        f.add(c);

        Button img = new Button("사진등록");
        img.setBounds(325, 300, 80, 30);              
        f.add(img);


        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Where your popup? Why are you using **AWT** instead of **Swing**?

Answer (score 1):

Please add actionlistener to your button to have some action. Currenly your button is not binded to any actionEvent so that is why you *wait wait wait... there is no event to (no image)*

`img.addActionListener(theReferenceWhichImplementsActionCommand);`

```
img.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
  {
    System.out.println("Button pressed");
  }
});
```

Please see [example1](http://www.java-examples.com/set-action-command-awt-button-example)
[Reference](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/adiehelp/v5r1m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.sun.api.doc/java/awt/Button.html)

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you need an `ActionListener` to your button and then show your Image for book.

Look at [using of ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).

I think you need to change your code in next way for adding action to your button:

```
    final Canvas c = new Canvas();
    c.setBounds(300, 100, 130, 180);
    c.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    c.setVisible(false);
    f.add(c);

    JButton img = new JButton("7");
    img.setBounds(325, 300, 80, 30);     
    img.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            c.setVisible(true);
            //create image for your canvas
        }
    });
    f.add(img);
```

And please change your **AWT** types to **Swing**, unless you really do not need AWT components.